# Angular - Recursive function throws error when calling itself?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a recursive function that works perfectly fine when outside of angular. It is all native JS but seems to throw errors when trying to use it within angular2/4.

**Function:**

```
convertToArray(object, keys) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            this.convertToArray(object[k], keys);
        }
        if (keys.indexOf(k) !== -1 && !Array.isArray(object[k])) {
            object[k] = [object[k]];
        }
    });
}
```

I invoke the method by:

```
console.log(this._utils.convertToArray(this.mapRulesData, ['rule']))
```

When I run it within my project, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'convertToArray' of undefined
```

When I do some `console.log` within the function, it appears to make it to this line before throwing the error:

```
this.convertToArray(object[k], keys);
```

Is there something special with angular when trying to have a method call itself in this manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is lost in your `function (k)` and does not refer to the object itself. Every `function` creates has it's own `this`.

Change it to [**arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Arrow function does not bind its own `this`.

```
convertToArray(object, keys) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(k => {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            this.convertToArray(object[k], keys);
        }
        if (keys.indexOf(k) !== -1 && !Array.isArray(object[k])) {
            object[k] = [object[k]];
        }
    });
}
```